# Merge multiple json objects to single object with same keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know looking this question might be simple, but I'm bit confused with the way of objects reacts in javascript. I tried to search as much as possible for a solution and couldn't find any.

Here, I wanted to send the below json request. **(EXPECTED OUTPUT)**

```
 {

    "request": {
        "command": "transaction",
         "commandData":{
          "type": "sale",
          "amount" : 0.00,
          "tenderType" : "credit",
          "referenceNumber": "",
          "kiosk" :{
              "machineName": "string",
              "clinicId": "string"
            }
          }
      }
}

{
    "request": {
        "command": "close",
        "commanddata":{
          }
      }
}

{
    "request": {
        "command": "status",
        "commanddata":{
         }
   }
}
```

For the above request, I have splitted as three json objects viz `tempJson1`, `tempJson2` and `tempJson3` and finally combine all the json objects and store in a variable called `tempJson`.

But, when I try to use `Object.assign()`, it is taking only the tempJson3 and not merging all three json objects.

Where am I missing? Any help?

```js
 var tempJson1 = {};
    tempJson1.request = {};
    
    tempJson1.request.command = "Transaction";
    tempJson1.request.commandData = {};
    tempJson1.request.commandData.type = "sale";
    tempJson1.request.commandData.amount = document.getElementById("amount").value || "";
    tempJson1.request.commandData.tendertype = document.getElementById("tendertype").value || "";
    //tempJson.request.requireToken = document.querySelector('.consent').checked;
    tempJson1.request.commandData.referenceNumber = "";
    tempJson1.request.kiosk = {};
    tempJson1.request.kiosk.machineName = document.getElementById("machineName").value || "";
    tempJson1.request.kiosk.clinicId = document.getElementById("clinicId").value || "";

    var tempJson2 ={}; 
    tempJson2.request = {};
    tempJson2.request.command = "close";
    tempJson2.request.commandData = {};
    
    var tempJson3 = {};
    tempJson3.request = {};
    tempJson3.request.command = "status";
    tempJson3.request.commandData = {};

    var tempJson = Object.assign({},tempJson1,tempJson2, tempJson3);
    //var tempJson = tempJson1.concat(tempJson2);
    console.log(tempJson);
    console.log("tempJson = " + JSON.stringify(tempJson));
```

```html
<div>
            <input type="hidden" id="amount"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="tendertype"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="machineName"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="clinicId"/>

        </div>
```

**PS: Need solution with pure javascript and no ES6.**

Comment: can you use ES6?

Comment: Nope.. without ES6 I need a solution

Comment: Can you please show what result are you expecting to receive? thanks

Comment: What exactly do you trying to accomplish? Do you A) want to merge all 3 objects and override common properties, B) create an array containing all 3 objects or C) make `request` an array?

Comment: If there is no way, I need to go for ES6, if you have any solution with ES6, please post it

Comment: @Ahmed, No more array here, combine all the three objects which is stored in a different variable. No override common properties

Comment: I was thinking is there any issue with the request format, if so it may thrown a error before displaying the console.log

Comment: @Alberto, I wanted to achieve the above mentioned json format which is clearly explained in the question.

Comment: @UI_Dev could you add expected output for `console.log(tempJson);` to your question? It's still not clear (at least for me) what result do you want..

Comment: @TrebleSnake, expected output is the json request which was mentioned in the question. Edited as well. tempJson is the merged object of all other three object

Comment: @UI_Dev Ok, your expected output is [NOT a valid JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=70ea6493ea4e4f639bd54a32889551d3). But I see now what you are trying to do, I'm gonna write an answer.

Comment: I think that you are saying that the output is what you are receiving to work with. But what I really want is the final output. The result of the merge of the 3 temp objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I got the question right, it seems you want to send 3 blocks of data as JSON payload for an HTTP request. Blocks are:

```
{

    "request": {
        "command": "transaction",
         "commandData":{
            // ...
          }
      }
}

{
    "request": {
        "command": "close",
        "commandData":{
          }
      }
}

{
    "request": {
        "command": "status",
        "commandData":{
         }
   }
}
```

But this is [not a valid JSON](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=70ea6493ea4e4f639bd54a32889551d3). You must have one entity (object or array in this case) as the root element. So I can think of these possible solutions:

1. Send 3 separated HTTP requests with one "request" JSON object in each request.
2. If you need to send all three in one request, you have to group it in some way.
   For example:

2.1. An array

```
[
  {
    "request": {
        "command": "transaction",
         "commandData":{
            // ...
          }
      }
  },
  {
    "request": {
        "command": "close",
        "commandData":{
          }
      }
  },
  {
    "request": {
        "command": "status",
        "commandData":{
         }
   }
  } 
]

// so the code would be:
var tempJson = [tempJson1, tempJson2, tempJson3];
```

2.2. An object with differently named properties:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "request": {
        "command": "transaction",
         "commandData":{
            // ...
          }
      }
  },
  "close": {
    "request": {
        "command": "close",
        "commandData":{
          }
      }
  },
  "status": {
    "request": {
        "command": "status",
        "commandData":{
         }
   }
  } 
}

// so the code would be:
var tempJson = {
  transaction: tempJson1, 
  close: tempJson2, 
  status: tempJson3
};
```

2.3. Or some kind of a combination of those.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same key again and again in one object.The "request" key is being used thrice inside the same object.So it will be replace the first two objects.

Comment: For this case only, I have created three separate objects.

Comment: But the key is same in the three objects.
tempJson1.request = {};
tempJson2.request = {};
tempJson3.request = {};
You need to name them as
 tempJson2.request2 = {} ,
tempJson3.request3 ={}

Comment: Yes, i too agree with that if i change the name, it will work, but this is what the request given. Is there any solution with this approach?

Comment: I am afraid not..you need to manipulate the object to have three keys.You have different 'commands' within the three objects.Why not name the request as per the command.

tempJson1.transactionRequest = {}
tempJson2.closeRequest = {}
 and so on..